# Is there any way to trigger firestore without cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my nodejs express app for my react backend, am accessing firestore using firebase service account key. is there any way to trigger firestore when a collection is created or deleted without Cloud Functions ?
I am not able to upgrade to blaze plan, so cannot use cloud functions in my firebase project.

below code is to delete notification whenever a post is unliked(ie. a doc will be deleted from likes collection).

```js
exports.deleteNotificationOnUnlike = functions.firestore
  .document("likes/{id}")
  .onDelete((snapshot) => {
    return db
      .doc(`/notifications/${snapshot.id}`)
      .delete()
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  });
```

how can i implement above code without cloud functions ?

Comment: Are you asking how to listen to Firestore updates on Node.js? That should be done as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen.  If you're having trouble making that work, please edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as following that guidance maximizes the chances that someone can help).

Comment: i am trying to create notification when there is change in firestore collections. i have made change in question, please hava a look @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That code uses Cloud Functions, which means it can't be run on a bare Node.js installation. If you want to run this code locally, you can use the [emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore) Firebase provides. Or if you want to create the equivalent on regular Node.js, you can use the link I provided in my first link to get started.

Comment: QuerySnapshot by checking change.type do the trick...Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Could you create an answer stating what you did to solve the issue for future readers to understand the steps performed? Thanks!