# Is there a way to use Firebase RTDB triggers inside simple NodeJS without Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the onUpdate firebase trigger. I migrated all firebase functions to the simple nodejs express server. But I am not sure if it is possible with triggers. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552743/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-firestore-without-cloud-functions) has similar issue but it is related to firestore.

If there is no way to migrate triggers, would you propose ways to replace this logic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no drop-in replacement for the Cloud Functions trigger syntax in an Express app, but you can build the equivalent functionality.

To listen to updates from Firebase Realtime Database in an Express app, you'd use the Firebase Admin SDK that Node.js and then implement an `on('value'` listener, as shown in the documentation on [listening for value events in Java and Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value).